# repairing a cast iron Garage Floor drain trap

Tags: plumbing, garage

The cover of the floor drain is cast iron and rusted badly. The floor drain basin is also cast iron and was full of dirt so I proceeded to clean it out.      The drain is 6.5" dia basin cup shape with a 2 3/8" ID drain pipe sticking up thru the center of the cup basin.  it drains by water filling the basin to the top of the pipe and then water spills over into the drain pipe.  After removing all the dirt and sludge in the bottom of the basin, I found that the bottom of the basin was lined with about 1/2" of a white ceramic filler ring of some sort.  On top of the ceramic ring was another ring about 3/8" thick which looked like solid silicone or of some sort of pliable gasket material.  It had shrunk in size and was cracked in 4 palaces.  What was the purpose/function of these rings of material in the bottom of the drain basin cup and do I need them?  Can I replace them and if so, what do you recommend?  Are replacement rings available?
Thank you....... jacfixit44

Comment: Are you able to post a photo?

Comment: Without a pic, the best guess would be to clean it out, remove the broken seal, and replace with caulk.

Comment: Currently I've cleaned it out, removed both the ceramic bottom gasket and top "rubber like" gasket/seal.  Then wire brushed it to remove loose rust, and coated with 'Extend'. Next I gave it a coat of Rust-O-Leum paint, and let it dry for a week.  Then I'll fill the bottom with Dry-Lock and let it dry.  Next I'm thinking I'll use that thin caulking that is used between concrete slab joints and cover the bottom of the bell .  I've used that type of caulking before on my driveway seams and it flows out very smooth when set. holds tight to the surface, and of course is waterpoof.  pic next week